# When we undertake an operation on an int, is the result temporarily stored in an int?

Tags: c++, c, types

I was solving a problem on an online judge using C and I came across this problem.

Constraint : t <= 10<sup>9</sup>
I got a Wrong Answer when I declared t to be an int, and an Answer Accepted when I declared it as a long long.

The solution involves the following mathematical calculation:

```
    m = (-3 + sqrt(12*t - 3))/(float)6 ;
```

I was thinking that perhaps `12 * t - 3` is getting stored in an int, though temporarily, which is giving an error. Could someone please tell me if I am right?

Comment: yup..it might be possible that..compiler checking for test case with t=10^9 which crossing the integer limit

Comment: Should we know what "WA" and "AC" mean? Are those some sort of error messages?

Comment: What is the datatype of `t`?

Comment: @Gabe WA-Wrong Answer,AC-Accepted

Comment: @EdHeal, when t is an int it gives a WA. But gives an AC when t is a long long.

Comment: @KamleshArya, I don't think that the online judge would cross the limit as it has mentioned the upper limit so explicitly. But what I think is that when t is an int, 12*t -3 gets stored in an int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Types smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` (or `unsigned int`) before calculations, but computation with `int` results in a new `int`.

If your result will overflow an `int`, it's best to make sure at least one of the operands is a type large enough to hold the result.

Comment: Of note here is that `12 * 1000000000` will overflow an `int`, leading to the wrong answer.

Comment: @Gabe: Well, `int` is allowed to be big enough to hold that, but typically is not.

Answer (score 0):

If t is an int `12*t` is an int for sure. The type inference in C expression is going from bottom up. It means that the (temporary) result of 12*t is stored in an 32-bit integer register, it overflows over the limit (which is around 2E+9) and you get wrong result. A clever compiler may warn you about it, because it may infer from the code this is going to happen in some cases.

If you declare t as `long long`, it has range up to 2^63 giving something like 8E+18. In this case also the expression `12*t` is typed `long long` and is stored in a 64 bit register (or a pair of 32 registers, if your computer does not have 64 bit registers) and the expression gives the correct result.

Comment: Surely the limit for a 32 bit int is 2^31 or 2^32, and surely 2*2^9 is 2^10?